# Adjusting Bundle Product Price Programmatically

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I’m working on a small tool for my client that dynamically updates quantity of items needed for certain project sizes (in square feet).

The entire page is built using jQuery. I managed to update all the product quantities but the total price at the end isn’t calculating correctly.

Basically what is happening is, I’m updating the values using $.val() and then calling the $.Change() event for those fields, like so :

```
jQuery(‘[name=”bundle_quantity_256″]’).val(PolyTen).change();
jQuery(‘[name=”bundle_quantity_257″]’).val(PolyTwo).change();
jQuery(‘[name=”bundle_quantity_251″]’).val(superBlue).change();
```

At the end when the total price calculates, it only applies the new values for the final item that was changed, the top two get ignored (only as far as the price calculation)

How can I update the price at the end when it displays? Current I am targeting the event like this

```
jQuery(“.bundle_price”).one(‘DOMNodeInserted’, function(e) {
});
```

That event fires once the price comes into view. Any help would be appreciated.

If you go to the page itself: https://concretefloorsupply.com/custom-kits/  to check it out, select U Epoxy It for the first dropdown, and One Day Flake for the second dropdown, and put any number between 200 and 200,000 for the square foot. Then click the tab that says “Create My Kit”